# Any tools or techniques for validating constraints programmatically between databases?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, validation, constraints

If you had two databases, that had two tables between them that would normally implement a one to one (or many to many) constraint but cannot since they are separate databases, how would you validate this relationship in an application or test?

Is there a simple way to do this? For example, a tool or technique that can, given a constraint type, tables and fields, does the validation.

I imagine that this isn't the first time this come up so I'm hoping people can share their solution.

Thanks.

Comment: How separate and different are your databases? Two different databases in one MSSQL server at one extreme, or one Access database and one Oracle database on a different server?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear, what programming language are you planning on using to accomplish the task?

> "If you had two databases, that had two tables between them that would normally implement a one to one (or many to many) constraint...."

Answer (score 0):

If you can set up linked servers you could achieve this effect using a trigger, but actually setting a constraint is as far as i know, impossible.

Comment: Yes, I am not trying to setup a constraint. I assumed this was impossible/impractical.  This is why I am looking to do this programmatically.

Comment: Are you able to set up a linked server?

Comment: I can look into this approach, I was not aware of this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me as though you're talking about referential integrity constraints.  [Hibernate Shards](https://www.hibernate.org/414.html) adds horizontal partitioning support to Hibernate so that you can have a single Hibernate model which is spread over multiple databases.  That said, I don't know if the project is still under active development, and it may complicate your life in other ways.  I'm not sure if it's compatible with JPA, for example.